# locally connected space X

Tags: general-topology

Find a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ from a locally connected space $X$
onto a non-locally connected space $Y$.

I am thinking if I start with $X=N$ that will be helpful but I get stuck after that because I am not able to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $N$

I will be very thankful for any help with this question.

Comment: I think a better strategy is to first choose the non-locally connected space $Y$. Not every choice will work, so it may take some work. But choosing $X$ first seems more like a complete stab in the dark to me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've meant $X=\mathbb{N}$, i.e. naturals. If you put the discrete topology on $X$ then every function $f:X\to Y$ is continous, no matter what $Y$ is. That's because every subset of $X$ is open, including $f^{-1}(U)$. So now if you take $Y$ to be any non-locally connected, countable space then you will find continous surjection $f:\mathbb{N}\to Y$. However it won't work if $Y$ is uncountable.

So here's another idea, the $Y$'s point of view. Take any non-locally connected space $Y$. Then define $X=Y$ as a set but put a discrete topology on $X$. Define $f:X\to Y$, $f(x)=x$.

Now $f$ is continous because topology on $X$ is discrete. Also obviously $f$ is onto.

$X$ is locally connected. Every discrete space is because singletons are open.

And $Y$ is not locally connected by the choice.

For a concrete example take $Y=\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual Euclidean topology. Since $Y$ is countable then you end up with $X\simeq\mathbb{N}$, the same idea you've started with.